# How to add NoReCaptcha on Asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

I've been using google recaptcha on my asp.net web application.
Now i heard people saying Google introduced a new NoReCaptcha plugin
(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html). I would like to use this new plugin,but i don't know where to start. I've used this guide to add the old ReCaptcha : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/aspnet

Do you know of a link that explains how to add NoReCaptcha plugin on asp.net ?

Comment: Here are the docs on how to use the new recaptcha regardless of the server technology https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/ Here how to do it in mvc http://venkatbaggu.com/google-recaptcha-asp-net-mvc/ Both should let you easily do the same for webforms.

Comment: @WiktorZychla my only concern about these links  is that i cant find a code that do validation on the server side. E.g with the old recaptcha i was using Page.IsValid

Comment: Second link, "validating user response", you shouldn't have missed that.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla i checked those links , but unfortunately google does not provide us with the sample code. So i found a solution at this site : http://www.sulware.com/Blog/?id=28

Answer (score 0):

For your convenience (and other similar questions in future) I've assembled an example approach to a WebForms control that renders and verifies the reCAPTCHA:

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2015/04/no-captcha-recaptcha-for-aspnet-webforms.html

You just put it on your web page:

```
<recaptcha:NoRecaptchaControl 
  ID="recaptcha" runat="server" 
  ClientIDMode="Static" Theme="clean" />
```

and verify

```
protected void button_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   if ( recaptcha.IsValid )
   {
     ...
   }
   else
   {
     ...
   }
 }
```